# Docker bind to machine ip rather than 0.0.0.0

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker machine and I opened a port.

However, the port is binding to 0.0.0.0 and not the ip that i assigned to the specific docker machine. This means that I wont be able to run two docker containers with services running on the same port.

What should I do? Any suggestion?

Comment: You can use docker swarm it creates a cooperative group of systems that can provide redundancy, enabling Docker Swarm failover if one or more nodes experience an outage.

Comment: when you run the container use -p IP:host_port:container_port

Answer (score 5):

I assume you're trying to expose ports via `docker run`.

According to https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/ you can specify to which interface you want to bind to:

> When you invoke docker run you can use either `-p IP:host_port:container_port` or `-p IP::port` to specify the external interface for one particular binding.

Comment: it works but it also binds to 0.0.0.0. How to prevent that?